# Android, how to open record sound using WebView

Tags: android, audio, webview, server, recorder

I need open sound recorder or camera when users press on this input using WebView then after recording, it uploads sound file to server when pressing submit.

```
 Image: <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" required>
 Sound: <input type="file" name="recordfile" id="recordfile" required>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code for open camera and sound recorder by webview for all Android versions

```
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
        // onActivityResult attached before constructor
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
        {
            // Update message
            // Update message
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try{

            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

            // Create camera captured image file path and name 
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
            + ".jpg");

            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

            // Set camera intent to file chooser 
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


        // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices

        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra("outputX", 40);
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra("outputY", 40);
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);


            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);

            return true;
        }

        //For Android 4.1 only
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    });
```